# How do I get a Blackgold TV tuner working?

Tags: tv-tuner

I've bought a duel pci-e Freeview Blackgold TV tuner in the past, and have been unable to get it working under Linux.  They have released the Source Code.

How do I get this integrated into the Ubuntu 13.04/14.04 Kernel?

http://shop.blackgold.tv/epages/BT3159.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/BT3159/Categories/Support/Current_Drivers

`lspci` output...

```
00:00.0 Memory controller: NVIDIA Corporation CK804 Memory Controller (rev a4)
00:01.0 ISA bridge: NVIDIA Corporation CK804 ISA Bridge (rev b1)
00:01.1 SMBus: NVIDIA Corporation CK804 SMBus (rev a2)
00:02.0 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation CK804 USB Controller (rev a2)
00:02.1 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation CK804 USB Controller (rev a4)
00:06.0 IDE interface: NVIDIA Corporation CK804 IDE (rev f3)
00:07.0 IDE interface: NVIDIA Corporation CK804 Serial ATA Controller (rev f3)
00:08.0 IDE interface: NVIDIA Corporation CK804 Serial ATA Controller (rev f3)
00:09.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation CK804 PCI Bridge (rev a2)
00:0a.0 Bridge: NVIDIA Corporation CK804 Ethernet Controller (rev a3)
00:0b.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation CK804 PCIE Bridge (rev a3)
00:0c.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation CK804 PCIE Bridge (rev a3)
00:0d.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation CK804 PCIE Bridge (rev a3)
00:0e.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation CK804 PCIE Bridge (rev a3)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] HyperTransport Technology Configuration
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Address Map
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] DRAM Controller
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Miscellaneous Control
01:09.0 Multimedia audio controller: Creative Labs SB Audigy (rev 04)
01:09.1 Input device controller: Creative Labs SB Audigy Game Port (rev 04)
01:09.2 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Creative Labs SB Audigy FireWire Port (rev 04)
03:00.0 Multimedia controller: Philips Semiconductors SAA7231 (rev aa)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR242x / AR542x Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV630 XT [Radeon HD 2600 XT]
05:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV630 HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 2600 Series]
```

Comment: Are you yet interested on receiving support on this issue? Please inform in order to start looking for a solution together. Thank you. :)

Comment: yes please I would like some support

Comment: Hello. Good to know you're there. Well, first of all we need to know the results of your lspci command in a terminal, please edit your question and add the results in order to check if the device is being recognized and -probably- already installed, after which we can focus in a different thing. If not, we'll do something with the drivers provided in the support page that you mentioned in your question. Add the edit and we'll go on. This may take us a while, please be patience. Thank you.